# In JavaScript what is a ',' in a conditional

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

In this example:

```
for (var c = 0, e = a.length; c < e && !(d = b(c, a[c]), !1 === d)
```

And in this other:

```
if (d = b(c, a[c]), !1 === d)
```

Do those conditions return the first part, the second or both?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), and is not specific to conditionals or loops.